# Calling multiple methods with same name using SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have a SOAP webservice and in SOAP UI I see that there are methods with the same name. So, for example, there are 2 `CreateNewContact` methods, one of which takes 3 parameters and the other 4. Below are the stubs generated by SOAP UI

Method 1 Stub:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rfp="http://test.com/testWebservice/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rfp:CreateNewContact_FullName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rfp:fullName>?</rfp:fullName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rfp:email>?</rfp:email>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rfp:telNo>?</rfp:telNo>
      </rfp:CreateNewContact_FullName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Method 2 Stub:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rfp="http://test.com/testWebservice/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rfp:CreateNewContact_FirstLastName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rfp:firstName>?</rfp:firstName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rfp:lastName>?</rfp:lastName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rfp:email>?</rfp:email>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <rfp:telNo>?</rfp:telNo>
      </rfp:CreateNewContact_FirstLastName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I call the `CreateNewContact` method with 4 parameters using PHP SoapClient, it looks like I'm getting the response from the other method.

How can I specify which method to use using SoapClient?

Thanks,

Comment: How were all the different version of the Method `CreateNewContact()` implemented? Or rather, how was the `CreateNewContact()` implemented? Track that, and you may be half-way home to resolving the issue. If you wouldn't mind, You may just `Copy-Paste` a part of it here....

Comment: I've included the stubs for the separate methods generated by SoapUI. Not sure if it's sufficient. What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

As you can read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.handle.php#81750):

> If you are using WSDL based SOAP requests and you have more than one
> operation in your binding (with the same parameters), make sure the
> soap:operation style is set to rpc, NOT body! When you specify
> 'body' here, all that will be transmitted in the request is the
> parameters for the function call, and **SoapServer->handle() will use
> the first function it finds with the same parameter-makeup to handle
> the call**. The actual method to call will only be included in the
> request when your type is set to 'rpc', resulting in the expected
> behavior

Therefore, you should check in your WSDL the [operation element](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-0595/ggeil2/index.html), which provides binding information from the abstract operation to the concrete SOAP operation.
For example:

```
<definitions ....>;
    <binding .... >;
        <operation .... >;
           <soap12:operation soapAction="xs:anyURI" ?
                              soapActionRequired="xs:boolean" ?
                              style="rpc|document" ?
                              wsdl:required="xs:boolean" ? /> ?
        </soap12:operation>
    </binding>;
</definitions>
```

The `style` attribute value, if present, is a string that specifies the style for the operation. The style attribute indicates whether the operation is RPC-oriented (a messages containing parameters and return values) or document-oriented (a message containing documents). If the style attribute is omitted from the soap12:operation element, then the operation inherits the style specified or implied by the soap12:binding element in the containing wsdl:binding element.
So, in short, to solve your problem you should change the operation style from "document" to "rpc" in your WSDL.
As a further reference: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49169

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same with travelport universal API, I ended up modifying my local wsdl file to use different name for each method and it worked perfectly.